# How do I combine two tabs of the same excel file into one tab in Python w/ pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

The tabs have the same amount of columns with the same headers. I want to combine the two tabs.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

# Read out sheets
df1 = pd.read_excel("workbook.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
df2 = pd.read_excel("workbook.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet2")

# Concatenate dataframes
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2])

# Write to a new worksheet in existing excel file
with pd.ExcelWriter("workbook.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:  
    df3.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name="Sheet3")
```

See the [pandas IO tools documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#excel-files) for more customization options.